# order by not working as expected

Tags: sql

I would like to pull in all bday members between two dates - irrespective of year.. just with month and day.. i get the results properly retrieved, but not ordered as i expect...

i would need the records ordered month by month with days in ascending order - such that those members in one month is grouped with the days being in ascending order.. (i get it grouped by month but not by days in it)

query:

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM family_member 
  WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%m-%d') 
          BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('2013-07-1', '%m-%d') 
             AND DATE_FORMAT('2013-09-30', '%m-%d') 
  order by MONTH(dob)
          ,DAYOFMONTH(dob) 
          and status='a'
```

Comment: Which DBMS do you use?

Comment: It looks like mysql but why not just order by dob without month and dayofmonth?

Comment: to group by month not year probably

Comment: should `and status='a'` be part of the where clause and not the order by?

Comment: i missed =status='a' phrase.. was typed by mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to take out the `and` in the `order by`:

```
SELECT * FROM family_member 
  WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%m-%d') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('2013-07-1', '%m-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT('2013-09-30', '%m-%d') 
  order by MONTH(dob), DAYOFMONTH(dob), status='a'
```

As written, it's ordering by `MONTH(dob)`, then be the boolean result of `AND`ing `DAYOFMONTH(dob)` and `status='a'`

either that or you've inserted the `order by` in the middle of your `where` clause:

```
SELECT * FROM family_member 
  WHERE DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%m-%d') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT('2013-07-1', '%m-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT('2013-09-30', '%m-%d') 
     and status = 'a'
  order by MONTH(dob), DAYOFMONTH(dob)
```